# Show skybox in hololens using MRTK

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

I'm using Unity and MRTK to create an immersive application for the hololens (similar to Holotour). In this application, I need to simulate the sky. In Unity, a Skybox is sufficient to show this. However, in Hololens, it is not. How do I go about showing the sky/what's on the skybox in my Hololens? Thus far, I have tried adding a render texture for a camera high in the sky to an inverted sphere (i.e. a sphere that encompasses the playspace and shows the material of the sphere on the inside); but that doesn't seem to work...

Comment: why didnt the inverted sphere work?

Comment: Perhaps because it was getting culled by the camera clipping planes.

Comment: I realised I inverted the normals incorrectly. Having said that though, the render texture shows the view with respect to a single camera and thus only one direction. What I need is a stereoscopic/360 camera (and then apply its render texture?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HoloLens uses the Transparent camera display settings to determine how to clear the scene. If you change Clear Flags to Skybox, you should get your desired effect.

[image]

Comment: Thany you so much, this shows the Skybox! However, the objects in the app now seem to leave a trail (namely the MRTK sliders). Any idea why/how to fix this?

Comment: I'm not sure i have seen that before. Can you file an issue (with a video) at https://aka.ms/mrtk? That will help us track and investigate the issue.

Also, what versions of Unity and MRTK are you using?

Comment: After playing around with the app, I realised that the scene renders properly in the left eye, but not the right (right eyes has objects jitterring for whatever reason)

Comment: Which MRTK and Unity version?

Comment: I'm using Unity version 2019.2.8f1 and I am using the MRTK package: "Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Unity.Foundation.2.2.0"

Comment: After messing around with the application some more, I've realised that the smear/jitter is due to the depth buffer not clearing. To fix this, I went to Edit->Project Settings->XR Settings and changed "Stereo Rendering Mode" to "Multi Pass"

Comment: Thank you for the update! I will make note of that.

Answer (score 0):

In Window>Rendering>Lighting Settings, set "Skybox Material" to the skybox of your choice. Also make sure, that your Camera "ClearFlag" is set to "Skybox".

If in doubt, please refer to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/camera-in-unity).